# Code style in MonoDevelop

Tags: coding-style, monodevelop

I want to change the default code style in MonoDevelop 2.0 (like remove the spaces before argument list). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in MonoDevelop 2.0. Support for formatting settings was introduced in MonoDevelop 2.4.